# Adding a cert to jre cacert with keytool in NixOS

Tags: keytool, nixos

I am trying to run a java program that requires an https call to an external service. But I am getting the error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So I tried to add the certificate into the cacert using the command

```
keytool -import -alias MYALIAS -keystore /nix/store/10b0a6m8z23xw1ds0pmckmqfx1pvyjli-oraclejdk-8u161/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file FILE-CA.crt
```

but I get the error

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /nix/store/10b0a6m8z23xw1ds0pmckmqfx1pvyjli-oraclejdk-8u161/jre/lib/security/cacerts (Read-only file system)
```

Since my distro is NixOS I know that there probably is an way to do this in the /etc/nixos/configuration.nix, but how?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the error message. Did you quote like `'$JAVA_HOME/jre/`...`'` on the shell?

Comment: I tried to make the examples in the question as generic as possible, but I will update the error message to be shown with the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NixOS does not currently have a special option for this. You can check that using the [NixOS Options Search](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#java) or, for some more accuracy, the `nixos-option` command.

To me it seems that certificate is supposed to be part of your program's configuration, not part of your system configuration. You can use `keytool`'s `-keystore` option to specify a path that is in your home directory. You can then pass that keystore to the JVM using something like

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/my/key/store -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword
```

If your java program comes with some kind of wrapper, you may need to pass these java 'system properties' differently, or the wrapper may provide an easier option to configure this.

Ideally, you could package the program to make it self-contained, but it's hard to tell whether that's a good idea based on the information in your question.

Comment: So in my specific case I want to add the certificate to Intellij so that i can write programs that can do an call to an ssl service. I should then add the trustStore and password into the idea.vmoption file in an derivation of the idea-community?

Comment: IntelliJ has a .vmoptions file you should modify. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: Thank you, marking the answer resolved based on the vmoptions comment